# Firebase Token Issue for the higher version Lollipop and Marshmallow

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am integrating firebase to my app but the problem is that I am receiving the token below the lollipop, don't figure out why token is coming null for the lollipop. Here is my code.

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sixmod.com.client">
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!--GCM amitranjan@sixmod5 id-->
   <!-- AIzaSyBo-v2RUKKoe37pZwYeurtoDFw1egxy7fM-->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.sixmod.com.client.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sixmod.com.client.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/truck"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyLocalytic.MyApplication"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">



        <service android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyReceiver.BroadcastService" />



    <activity

            android:name="com.sixmod.FragmentContainerActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!--<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCsguzmCQrHlTaBQ_6ixFyQUk" />-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBo-37pZwYeurtoDFw1egxy7fM " />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
            android:value="221c5b778e92fdd345fa63e09"/>


        <meta-data android:name="LOCALYTICS_APP_KEY" android:value="7f652c5db10aa2dbd542-d159-11e5-6885-002dea3c3994"/>        <receiver
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyLocalytic.LocalyticCustomReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

                <category android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyLocalytic"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.service.MyOrderService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

        <!--<meta-data
            android:name="LOCALYTICS_APP_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR-LOCALYTICS-APP-KEY"/>-->
       <!-- <receiver
            android:name="com.localytics.android.ReferralReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="7f652c5db10aa2dbd5b87f7-80b0ac42-d159-11e5-6885-002dea3c3994" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.notificationFireBase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.notificationFireBase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.notificationFireBase.RegistrationIntentService">

        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is called when the InstanceID token
     * is initially generated so this is where you would retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
       // sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
        OkHttpClient client= new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body=new FormBody.Builder().add("token", token).build();
        Request request=new Request.Builder().url("https://logizoapp-cf159.firebaseio.com/").build();// enter php url
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FragmentContainerActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

From Fragment Class

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
Log.i("regToken", "FCM Registration Token: " + token);
```

Comment: Can you please add the manifest.xml also?

Comment: the error that you are asking about is because of two API's crossing their ways.

Comment: Just use one api (FCM)

Comment: which api i have to remove, if they are crossing then token key is also not generated for the lower version, what you think ?

Comment: i replaced manifest with your edited manifest but getting same error :07-06 00:10:38.021 10684-10684/com.sixmod.com.client I/regToken: FCM Registration Token: null

Comment: i also made one separate demo project  , same error i am getting , it's working for lower version.

Comment: When are you calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()? Could you provide more context around this call?

Comment: @ArthurThompson  , i need the token so that i can send it to server side, for the some device i am getting for the some i don't, I done the demo to but still the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219294/firebase-token-issue-in-some-device?noredirect=1#comment63864413_38219294

Comment: Are you getting the onTokenRefresh callback? If you never get this callback then your token is never generated, be sure to uninstall and reinstall the app to ensure the callback is fired.

Comment: @ArthurThompson for the Karbon mobile it's also not calling onToken Refresh but i am getting the token when i print on the mainActivity and for the MotoE2 device neither token is generated from the main activity nor token refresh is called . Many times i rebooted my device as well as uninstall and install the app.

Comment: sry .. @ArthurThompson for the Karbon mobile it's calling onToken Refresh aswell as i am getting the token when i print on the mainActivity and for the MotoE2 device neither token is generated from the main activity nor token refresh is called . Many times i rebooted my device as well as uninstall and install the app.

Comment: If the onTokenRefresh callback is not fired then anywhere you call getToken you will get null, what version of Google Play Services is running on the MotoE2?

Comment: @ArthurThompson on MotoE2 it's 9.2.56 same in Karbon

Answer (score 0):

1) Just use Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) API replacing the GCM.

2) Demo Project: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

3) For more information : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

update:

Your project is not right. It has many error possibilities.

*The reason for this is you are using 2 api's (GCM and FCM in one project.)*

**Don't use GCM because it is only the older version of FCM. Therfore, use only FCM. The c2dm function you using here is not now in the FCM verison. It is old.**

***But you may try the following manifest code: Just Copy and Paste***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sixmod.com.client">
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <!--GCM amitranjan@sixmod5 id-->
   <!-- AIzaSyBo-v2RUKKoe37pZwYeurtoDFw1egxy7fM-->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/truck"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyLocalytic.MyApplication"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">



        <service android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyReceiver.BroadcastService" />



    <activity

            android:name="com.sixmod.FragmentContainerActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!--<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCsguzmCQrHlTaBQ_6ixFyQUk" />-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBo-37pZwYeurtoDFw1egxy7fM " />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
            android:value="221c5b778e92fdd345fa63e09"/>


        <meta-data android:name="LOCALYTICS_APP_KEY" android:value="7f652c5db10aa2dbd542-d159-11e5-6885-002dea3c3994"/>        <receiver
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyLocalytic.LocalyticCustomReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

                <category android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.MyLocalytic"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.service.MyOrderService"
            android:exported="false">
        </service>

        <!--<meta-data
            android:name="LOCALYTICS_APP_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR-LOCALYTICS-APP-KEY"/>-->
       <!-- <receiver
            android:name="com.localytics.android.ReferralReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>-->

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="7f652c5db10aa2dbd5b87f7-80b0ac42-d159-11e5-6885-002dea3c3994" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.notificationFireBase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name="com.sixmod.com.sixmod.notificationFireBase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

***Old Answer:***

**Do not use** :

> ```
> > getActivity().startService(new
> > Intent(getActivity(),RegistrationIntentService.class));
> ```

**This is automatically registered from the Manifest file. You don't need the RegistrationIntentService.java . remove It**

1) First thing is use: `*(For this update the Google Repository and Google Play Service from the Android SDK Manager.)*`

> `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'`

2) Uncomment it:

> `sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);`

3) You don't need the RegistrationIntentService.java . Remove this. It can cause your registration token not to be received.

Comment: getting same issue

Comment: show the manifest.xml file. You can edit your answer for adding this file.

Comment: Edit option is just below the question.

Comment: Sorry it took some time : i edited the changes and i am not calling sendRegistrationToServer() method

Comment: Thanks Alot, i made the changes in the gradle also as per you mentioned ,but still having the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116560/discussion-between-saini-and-barnali-bhattacharjee).

Comment: did you got any clue ? I have done demo to facing same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219294/firebase-token-issue-in-some-device?noredirect=1#comment63864413_38219294

Comment: please do not call getToken method from the Activity. The onTokenRefresh() interface method will detect it automatically and handle it. Inspite this you can store that InstanceId in your sql database or file or shared pref for the purpose of showing it in the App

Comment: Just follow the github project, it has no error. it simply explains the whole procedure

Comment: this tag is also not getting printed.. Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken); and on the above comment ,i had same issue and given you the link